# view set default size when we change the device orientation

Tags: iphone, ios, view

Why the uiview changes orientation automatically when change the device orientation and not completely scrolling of uitableview

```
    (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
        // Return YES for supported orientations.
        if (self.medcategoryPopOver!=nil) {
            [self.medcategoryPopOver dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        }

        if  (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
            mediconDisplay.hidden=NO;
            return YES;

        } else if (interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
            mediconDisplay.hidden=YES;
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            mediconDisplay.hidden=YES;
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please explain your question is not proper...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check the size of default view. If it will be bigger by default than the scrolling will not be enabled...

Answer (score 0):

The orientation is changing because you are returning YES (TRUE) for all orientations.  If you want to limit the orientations, you need to return YES (TRUE) only for those that you want, otherwise return NO (FALSE).